# Linked Service to MySQL. Error converting invalid input with source encoding UTF-8 using ICU

Tags: mysql, azure-data-factory

In `Azure Data Factory` I created a `MySQL` linked service. But during data preview I get error:

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Support] (50311) Error converting invalid input with source encoding UTF-8 using ICU. Rejected bytes began with: CFC2.. Activity ID:e3b7fc32-8fcd-4981-b0e3-f377c6b17150

Most likely a coding error. But I did not find how to configure it

Here is `JSON` of linked sevice

```
{
    "name": "n_trans_connection",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "MySql",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "server=some-server;port=some-port;database=u5256_mti_spr;user=some-user;sslmode=1;usesystemtruststore=0",
            "encryptedCredential": "some-hash"
        }
    }
}
```

How to set up encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is when you preview data , I don't think that is coding issue . Can you please check if you select a different table and if you face the same issue .